# HttpClient - Execute an async method before every call to SendAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, asp.net-core-identity, ihttpclientfactory

I'm in an ASP.Net Core environment and want my classes to use a named `HttpClient` which they retrieve from an `IHttpClientFactory`.
They need to add a Bearer token into the Authorization header. In order to do that, they need to make an async call which will either get the token from an OAuth endpoint, or retrieve it from the cache.

I know there are calls for `services.AddHttpClient(...)` which I can use to modify the `HttpClient` instances which are retrieved from the `IHttpClientFactory`. However that only allows for sync methods (It is an `Action<ServiceProvider, HttpClient>`), because `IHttpClientFactory.GetClient(string name)` is sync too.

Is there anything built into that I can use to make that async call and add the header either when retrieving the client, or when making the request by calling `SendAsync(...)`?

Comment: But how will you manage if Async call occurred.. I mean, token  must be fetched using sync call in order to do other sequence calls,, otherwise later call will not have the token.. make sense?

Comment: @AmitSoni async doesn't mean parallel, `async` means non-thread blocking using the `async await` block, that's what the question is about

Comment: @AmitSoni normally you either do middleware of [DelegatingHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientbuilderextensions.addhttpmessagehandler?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0). Also would be interesting why do you believe "token *must be fetched using sync call*" - I don't believe there is such restriction anywhere (quite opposite - async is preferred in asp.net core)

Comment: @OlegI is right, I'm talking about asynchronous programming, not parallel programming.

Comment: @wertzui you are looking for https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+add+delegateinghandler+auth

Answer (score 0):

I think that AOP, for Aspect Oriented Programming, could interest you for your kind of problems.

The point of this paradigm is to increase the modularity of your code by separating the different sections and defining rules called pointcut to execute one or many specific functions before, after, when it calls an exception, etc.

In your case, you could define a Pointcut that execute your async method on entry (on the startup of the function but before any code is called) of `SendAsync`.

To do so, there are many AOP framework existing in C#. I know PostSharp is a good framework for AOP but I encourage you to try many of them to find which one fit the most for your needs.

Here is the link to PostSharp : https://www.postsharp.net/

I hope my answer could help you.
Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

@alexei-levenkov pointed me in the right direction in the comments.
[DelegatingHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientbuilderextensions.addhttpmessagehandler?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) is the way to solve this problem.

Actually I'm using `Microsoft.Identity.Web` which comes with its own `AddMicrosoftIdentityAppAuthenticationHandler()` which will automatically insert the handler, I was looking for.